# Displaying a view from a controller using phalcon php

Tags: php, ajax, phalcon

Happy new year guys!

I'm trying to wire up a small phalcon project from scratch, but I am having trouble displaying a view. I am able to call the controller action using an ajax request from my js file

```
$('#create_user').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/user/create",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (resp) {
            console.log('successfully getting create page: ' + resp);
        },
        error: function (x, status, error) {
            console.log(x.responseText);
            console.log(error);
        },
        complete: function () {
        }
    });
});
```

which I confirmed by setting a breakpoint in the action.

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {

    }

    public function createAction()
    {
        $this->assets
            ->addJs('js/jquery.js')
            ->addJs('js/user.js');

        $this->view->pick('/users/create');
    }
}
```

However, the view doesn't seem to get picked, and the html text of the current view is returned to the error function of the ajax request. 
I don't konw what i'm doing wrong, please help

Comment: Where does the `/user/create` (single) route lead to and why are you later on using `/users/create` (plural) ?

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo, they should both be `/users/create` and that leads to the users folder in my `views` folder, which contains the `create.phtml` file

Comment: And how do you expect AJAX call to get data from a `phtml` file?

Comment: I'm sorry Dainis, my response was completely incorrect. `/user/create` leads to the `createAction` in the `UserController`, while `/users/create` leads to the `users` folder in my `views` directory, which contains the `create.phtml` file. So sorry for the confusion.

Comment: In that case, what are you trying to achieve? Ajax call should execute backend php actions and return plain data. Like, `createAction` should gather request data, store, validate it etc. and after that return `true`, `false` `[id: 1]` or similair data for JS to display. You do not generate view in ajax. Ajax is like: "Hey m8, do this!" and it should answer: "done" not "go and see it"

Comment: Oh, I think understand what you mean. I was trying to render a new view using the `createAction`, which I thought would be achieved by calling `$this->view->pick('/users/create');`. So how do I go about rendering that view?

Answer (score 0):

The right way of doing that should be using the phalcon mvc structure.

Your project directory should look like this(basic example):

```
-app
    -controllers
    -models
    -views
-public
```

If you respect this structure you actually don't need to pick your views like this
`$this->view->pick('/users/create');`

You only have to set the path of your views directory into the view service

```
$di->setShared('view', function () use ($config, $di) {

    $view = new View();
    $view->setViewsDir("path/to/your/views");
    $view->setLayoutsDir("path/to/your/layuts");

    $view->registerEngines(array(
        '.volt' => function ($view, $di) use ($config) {

            $volt = new VoltEngine($view, $di);

            $volt->setOptions(array(
                'stat' => true,
                'compileAlways' => true
            ));

            return $volt;
        },
        '.phtml' => 'Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Php'
    ));

    return $view;
});
```

If you want to receive a json response you have to send one first, so
your controller should look like this

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {

    }

    public function createAction()
    {

        $this->assets
            ->addJs('js/jquery.js')
            ->addJs('js/user.js');

        $this->response->setJsonContent(["data" => ["Your data"]]);
        $this->response->send();
    }
}
```

And your js function should now receive a json response with a data object in it